# Setting UITableViewCells of programmatically made UITableView in UIViewController with swift

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, swift

Okay so my goal is to draw custom cells into a UITableView that is programmatically made in a UIViewController. I have a custom cell class called KillFeedTableViewCell that also has a .xib

I made sure in the xib that the cells identifier is KillFeedTableViewCell which is what I also used as the identifier in the code below

The problem I'm having is that it simply won't run. I get no errors when I run and the tableView looks perfect when I run, there is just no cells. I also have a few lines to print text to the console to make sure the tableView functions are running and they arent..

Any help is appreciated, thanks!!

At the beginning of FirstViewController

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{
    //code

    var tableView:UITableView = UITableView()

    //code
}
```

later in the file I set up tableView like this

```
    var fullHeight:CGFloat = self.view.bounds.size.height-50
    tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, fullHeight, self.view.bounds.size.width, 0)
    // height is zero because you drag the tableView up filling the screen
    tableView.alpha = 0.5
    self.view.addSubview(tableView)
```

Finally at the end of FirstViewController right before the bracket that closes the class I have the necessary tableView functions plus some...

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
       var tempData = serverAPIHandler.getKillCount(username)
       var tempData2 = JSONSwift(tempData)
       println("table view kill count") // this is here so i know the code runs but this never shows up in the log
       return tempData2["kill_count"].intValue

}
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView!) -> Int {
    return 1
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell     {
    let cell: KillFeedTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("KillFeedTableViewCell") as KillFeedTableViewCell
    println(cell) // this is here so i know the code runs but this never shows up in the log
    return cell;
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {
    println("Row \(indexPath.row) selected")
}
```

Comment: Looks like you're not setting the table view's `delegate` or `dataSource`...

Comment: @mattt haha how do I do this? I'm fairly new... I'm 17 and self taught, this app is going to be for the game "Senior Assassins" next year.. when I'm a senior.

Comment: delegate is a property on the TableView, set it to equal self. You should also declare that you (self) conform to the UITableViewDelegate protocol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to remember to register the Nib file (usually done in viewDidLoad)

```
UINib *cellNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"cell" bundle:nil];
[self.tableView registerNib:cellNib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
```